# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition 16.7.0 hanging

Tags: visual-studio

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition 16.7.0 (at the time of writing the latest version).

If I create an empty project I have no problems at all, however if there is even one C# file then Visual Studio becomes absolutely useless. I've observed the following:

1. CPU usage hovers around the 40% mark.
2. Loading a file takes over 5 seconds.
3. Intellisense fails to recognise anything.
4. Every minute or so the entire application will hang for a few seconds.
5. After a few minutes it hangs and does not recover.

This did not occur before I upgraded to 16.7.0, but as for what I was on before I'm not certain.  I've tried a number of routes:

1. Removing the .vs folder.
2. Removing the project and solution and re-creating them.
3. Running Visual Studio in SafeMode (this simply brought up a large number of exceptions when trying to load a project).
4. Running the ResetSettings switch.
5. A fresh installation of Windows 10 x64.
6. Disabling the `Load projects faster` option.
7. All extensions are disabled.

Here is what the 'status' area looks like initially during project load and then while hanging:

[image]

[image]

1. How can I fix this?
2. Failing that, how can I roll back to an earlier release?

Comment: Updates of version 16.x.y don't become stable until y increments to at least 2, preferably 3.  Before that you're the agile victim that tests their changes, use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Bug.  Such updates usually come fast at first, within a week.  Recovery instructions are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release).

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding stable releases.

I've been using VS since VS6 and in the past few years the quality has dropped like a stone. Something in MS has changed and there's a complete lack of care. To be honest I care as much about submitting a bug report as they do about their product.

Thanks for the recovery instructions, I've already been through them but unfortunately they don't apply to the community version.

I've got a trial of the professional version, but it's time to maybe start looking at other IDEs.